# Numpy array limiting operation X[X < {value}] = {value}

Tags: python, numpy

I came across the following in a piece of code:

```
X = numpy.array()
X[X < np.finfo(float).eps] = np.finfo(float).eps
```

I found out the following from the documentation:

> **class numpy.finfo(dtype)**:
>
> Machine limits for floating point types.
>
> Parameters:
>
> dtype : float, dtype, or instance
>
> Kind of floating point data-type about which to get information.

I understand that `np.finfo(float).eps` returns the lowest represent-able float value and that `X[X < np.finfo(float).eps] = np.finfo(float).eps` makes sure that any value less than `np.finfo(float).eps` is not contained in the array `X`, but I'm unable to understand how exactly that happens in the statement of the form `X[X < {value}] = {value}` and what it means. Any help is appreciated much.

Comment: What does `print(X < np.finfo(float).eps)` output? What happens when you index a NumPy array with other arrays/lists/tuples? If you know the answer to both questions, you know what the whole statement does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time I saw it was as a way to replace `NaNs` in an array

Basically the conditional `X < np.finfo(float).eps` creates a boolean mask of `X`and then `X` is iterated over replacing values that have a `True` associated with them.

So for instance,

```
x=np.array([-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
x[x < 0] = 0
```

Here the mask array would look like,

```
[True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Its a quicker way of doing the following with large arrays,

```
x=np.array([-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
for y, idx in enumerate(x):
    if y < 0:
        x[idx] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fancy way of changing values of an array and changing values if condition is met.
On an easy example:

```
X = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=5)
print(X) # array([ 1, 17, 92,  9, 11])
X[X < 50] = 50 # Change any value lower than 50 to 50
print(X) # array([50, 50, 92, 50, 50])
```

Basically this changes array `X` if you don't make a copy of it and former values are lost forever. Using `np.where()` would achieve same goal, but it would not override the original array.

```
X = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=5)
print(X) # array([ 1, 17, 92,  9, 11])
np.where(X < 50, 50, X) # array([50, 50, 92, 50, 50])
print(X) # array([ 1, 17, 92,  9, 11])
```

Extra info:
[Fancy indexing](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Indexing.html) You need to scroll a bit down tho (idk how to copy at specific header)

Answer (score 0):

When we index a numpy array `X` with another array `x`, the output is a numpy array with values corresponding to the values of `X` at indices corresponding to the values of `x`.
And `X < {value}` returns a numpy array which has boolean values `True` or `False` against each item in `X` depending on whether the item passed the condition `{item} < {value}`. Hence, `X[X < {value}] = {value}` means that we're assigning the value `{value}` whenever an array item is less than `{value}`. The following would make things more clear:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 0]
>>> X = numpy.array(x)

>>> X < 1
array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
   False, False,  True])

>>> X[X < 1] = -1
>>> X
array([ 1,  2, -1,  3,  4, -1,  5,  6, -1,  7,  8, -1])

>>> X[x]
array([ 2, -1,  1,  3,  4,  1, -1,  5,  1,  6, -1,  1])
```

P.S. : The credit for this answer goes to @ForceBru and his comment above!